# PHP Slim 3 API Middleware class can't methods from __invoke?

Tags: php, api, slim

I'm trying to do some very basic key validation for my API, simply checking a provided key attribute against a key stored in the database.

I've got a middleware class that i'm adding to the slim object using

```
$app->add(new auth());
```

where auth.php is my class.

I have it working and i'd like to split the code in to functions however I can't seem to call functions from within __invoke without getting a Slim Application Error.

Right now I have

```
public function __invoke($request, $response, $next){
        try {
            $user_key = $request->getAttribute('route')->getArguments()['key'];

            ...
            //fetch key from database code
            ...

            if($user_key==$api_key){
                $response = $next($request, $response);
            }
            else{
               $response->getBody()->write("Invalid API Key");
            }
        } 
        catch (PDOException $e) {
               $response->getBody()->write("An error has occurred");
        }        
        return $response;
    }
```

Which works, but i'd like to move the fetch code in to its own function e.g

```
public function fetchKey(){
            ...
            //return key
            ...
    }
```

and call `$api_key = fetchKey();` however this causes a Slim error.

This is probably really simple but does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: If this exactly what you tried, the problem is probably the missing `$this` keyword. you should write it as `$api_key = $this->fetchKey();`. And please consider adding error details to your question, because **Slim Error** is the general error title shown to the user, but we need more details to be able to help.

Comment: Thank you that was the problem, i'll make sure to do that next time.

Comment: Please add the answer to the "Answers" section and mark it as accepted so that it's easier for other users to find the solution.